# Can't find the second highest salary in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

[image: employees table]

and executing the following query

```
select distinct lastname, firstname, max(salary) as salary
from employees
where salary not in (select max(salary) from employees)
group by lastname, firstname
```

I get the following result:

[image: results of query]

I want to find all the names of the employees that have the second highest salary which in the given table are all those with 6000 salary, but the only answers I could find was the above query. I am looking for some time now another way to do so but I can't find anything.

I am using SQL Server. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: @simbabque I think that he only wants people with second highest salary

Comment: Hint : `dense_rank()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank()` window function for this:

```
select * from (
    select employees.*, dense_rank() over(order by salary desc) rnk from employees
) t
where  rnk = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The answer is exactly what i needed and it also help me find out about dense_rank().Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you have Sql Server 2005 or higher you could use [DENSE_RANK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql).

```
with a as(
  select lastname,firstname,salary,
  dense_rank()over(order by salary desc)r
  from employees
)
select lastname,firstname,salary
from a where r=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below Sql query

```
DECLARE @SecondHighestSalary Int
SELECT TOP 1  @SecondHighestSalary = salary FROM (
   SELECT TOP 2 salary 
   FROM employees 
   ORDER BY salary DESC) AS emp 
ORDER BY salary ASC

SELECT * FROM employees where salary = @SecondHighestSalary
```

You can try this for getting n-th highest salary, where n = 1,2,3....(int)

```
SELECT TOP 1 salary FROM (
   SELECT TOP n salary 
   FROM employees 
   ORDER BY salary DESC) AS emp 
ORDER BY salary ASC
```

Hope this will help you.